# passing char array as function parameters in C

Tags: c, arrays, parameter-passing

I want to copy `arr2` to `arr` and pass `arr` as a function paramater

```
void func(char * array)
{}

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    char arr[6][50];
    char arr2[][50]={"qweeeaa","bbbb","ffaa","eeaa","aaaa","ffaa"};

    for(a=0; a<6;a++)
    {
        strcpy(arr[a], arr2[a]);
    }

    func(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

But I can not pass `arr` as a function parameter. I get

```
[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'func' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
[Note] expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'char (*)[50]'
```

I am using `MinGW GCC 4.8.1`

Comment: `[c] 2D array parameter` - I find it incredible to believe that search wouldn't yield *something* helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type you pass and the type the function expects do not match. Change the function to receive a pointer to an array:

```
void func(char (*array)[50])
{

}
```

Other problems:

1) You haven't declared a prototype for `func()` either. In pre-C99 mode, compiler would assume the function returns an `int` and this would cause problem.
In C99 and C11, missing prototype makes your code invalid. So either declare the prototype at the top of the source file or move the function above `main()`.

2) Include appropriate headers (`<stdio.h>` for printf etc).